# Hide header title in ShieldUI grid

Tags: gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I am new in ShieldUI and I have used ShieldUI grid in my project.In grid have some column which contain images column and for those column I dont want to show title.I have used following line of code.

```
{ field: "", title: "", columnTemplate: $("#nameTemplate").html(), width: "217px", filterable: false, width: "35px", attributes: { style: "text-align:center;cursor:pointer" } },
```

But in title place it display [object object].So how can I hide the title in header?
Also on click of that event I want redirect to some other action.So how can I capture click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting title to something different, that will not be shown, like `title: "&nbsp;"`